# Start date and end date in Angularjs in same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, angularjs-scope

What is the best way to create a start date and end date in Angularjs? I have the following code below which uses the same controller for both. Is it best practice to create a separate controller for each datepicker? My intent is to have a search button that will take input from both datepickers and then do some backend processing.

My HTML

```
<input type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
    ng-model="startdt" is-open="opened" 
    datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
    ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="startopen($event)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

My Javascript

```
        ///////////// BEGIN Datepicker code
    $scope.today = function () {
        $scope.startdt = $filter('date')((new Date()), "dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        $scope.enddt = $filter('date')((new Date()), "dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    };
    $scope.today();


    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    $scope.startopen = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
    };

            $scope.endopen = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
    };
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
```

Comment: directive would be an better option to move this content.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that you can set the value of a datapicker (the bound object aka model) to a Date object instead of a formatted date string. Since picking a date in the frontend will also set the value to a Date object, this way you can always expect to be working with a Date object.

Comment: Since they are interconnected I don't see why you would want separate controllers as you would then need to wire them together through a service or events broadcast

Comment: You would filter based on the dependent `ng-model` in your scope